# Find the volume of the waist of a sphere from 30 degrees S latitude $\frac{2 \pi}{3}$ to 30 degrees N latitude $\frac{2 \pi}{3}$

Tags: calculus

Find the volume of the waist of a sphere from  30 degrees  S latitude $(\frac{2 \pi}{3})$ to 30 degrees N latitude $(\frac{\pi}{3})$.

My inclination is to find the volume of the sphere and then subtract the volumes of the two cones cut out by those angles. I am a little confused because I wonder if it will work considering the volume of the "waist" may contain parts of the cones and the cones are not flush with the sphere. Also, is waist even a mathematically accurate definition? I have never heard this before.

$$ \int_{0}^{2 \pi} \int_{0}^{\pi} \int_{0}^{a} \rho^{2}\sin{\phi}d\rho d\phi d\theta - 2\int_{0}^{2 \pi} \int_{0}^{\frac{2\pi}{3}} \int_{0}^{a}| (\rho cos{\phi})\rho^{2}\sin{\phi}|d\rho d\phi d\theta $$

Am I on the right track?

Answer (score 1):

I think what is meant is that you have to find the volume of a "band" or "slice" of the circle, as follows:

$$ V=2\int_{0}^{2 \pi} \int_{\frac{\pi}{3}}^{\frac{\pi}{2}}\int_{0}^R r^2\sin \phi d\phi d\theta dr=\frac{2}{3}\pi R^3$$

The limits on the $\phi$-integral are as they are since we are integrating from  $\frac{\pi}{2}- 30 ^\circ=\frac{\pi}{2}-\frac{\pi}{6}=\frac{\pi}{3}$ down to the equator at $\frac{\pi}{2}$.

Let me know if I should include a drawing of the thing.

Comment: Wow. That is fairly simple. Thanks! I do not need  a drawing, but I would love to know how to make a drawing myself. Can you direct me?

Comment: I'll try! Draw a sphere centered in a coordinate system so that the $z$-axis is vertical. Now go $\pi/3$ up from the equator along the surface of the sphere. Now cut off everything above a plane which is parallel with the $x,y$-plane and goes through that point. Do the same for the southern hemisphere.

Comment: Thanks! I thought you knew some way to draw it in Latex ha ha ha.

Comment: @Zeta10 Hehe, yeah, that would be quite involved I think, so unfortunately not! :)